# Codeigniter 3 enviar arquivo com extensão PFX

Tags: php, codeigniter, mime-type

Preciso fazer Upload de um arquivo com a extensão `.pfx` (certificado digital).

Estou usando a `library` `Upload` do `CodeIgniter` da seguinte forma: 
Estou colocando a extensão **allowed_types** mas não envia. Retorna: **O tipo de arquivo que você está tentando fazer upload não é permitido.**

```
$config['upload_path'] = $pasta;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pfx';
$config['max_size'] = 100000;
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

$this - > load - > library('upload');
$this - > upload - > initialize($config);
if ($this - > upload - > do_upload('userfile')) {
    echo json_encode(array('image1' = > $this - > upload - > data('file_name'), 'file_ext' = > str_replace(".", "", $this - > upload - > data('file_ext')), 'error' = > 0, 'mensage' = > 'Arquivo enviado com sucesso.'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('mensage' = > $this - > upload - > display_errors(), 'error' = > 1));
}
```

Comment: faça um `var_dump` no `$config` e no `$_FILES` por favor.

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\application\controllers\Upload.php:127:
array (size=4)
  'upload_path' => string 'C:/wamp64
/www/public/clientes/lumer/certificado/' (length=48)
  'allowed_types' => string 'pfx'
 (length=3)
  'max_size' => int 100000
  'encrypt_name' => boolean true

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\application\controllers\Upload.php:127:
array (size=1)
  'userfile' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'LUMER_INFORMATICA_LTDA_ME10422724000187
.pfx' (length=43)
      'type' => string 'application
/octet-stream' (length=24)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp64
\tmp\php6D29.tmp' (length=25)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 9527

Comment: você inicializou as configurações? `$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: sim inicializei dessa forma

Comment: Faça a alteração no post por favor! :)

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro ocorre porque o framework não está achando essa extensão na lista de `mime types`, ou seja, ele não sabe o que é nem como tratar um arquivo `.pfx`. Pra resolver, abra `config/mimes.php` da sua aplicação e acrescente a seguinte linha ao final do `array()`:

```
'pfx' => array('application/octet-stream'),
```

Fonte: [Preferences](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload#preferences); [get_mimes()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=mime#get_mimes); [Mime type do pfx](http://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mime.html).

Comment: vou fazer isso, assim que fazer os teste posto aqui se deu certo

Comment: mesmo colocando a linha no mimes da o erro e não faz upload do .pfx

Comment: Verifiquei o tipo correto no log do console e editei a resposta. Tente novamente.

Comment: Testou novamente?

Comment: testei, mesmo assim não enviar e testei em servidores diferente, dai fiz um upload em php em utilizar a library upload, mais tentar a resolver esse problema.

Comment: Estranho. Aqui pra mim esse tipo de arquivo apareceu como `application/octet-stream`. Depois que alterei *config/mimes.php* funcionou direitinho. Lembre-se de que além de *config/mimes.php* vc tb deve usar `$config['allowed_types'] = 'pfx';` no seu `controller`.

Comment: sim fiz isso também estou achando muito estranho e se mudar para jpg e enviar ele envia, mais vou conferir certinho e qualquer coisa te retorno. :)

Answer (score 0):

Além de atualiza seus arquivos MIMES, utilize também o tipo de header application/x-pkcs12,

Ou seja:

```
'pfx'   =>  array('application/octet-stream', 'application/x-pkcs12')
```